# How to create a PDF on Node.js using PDFMake and vfs_fonts?

Tags: pdfmake

It looks like this [question](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/642) has been [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41314411/create-a-link-in-a-pdf-with-pdfmake-in-server-side-with-node) quite a few [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677412/server-side-fonts-directory-in-pdfmake-in-meteor-app) with older versions of PDFMake, but hasn't been updated with what appears to be the latest directory structure. Plus, copying fonts into a root "fonts" folder isn't great.

How in the world do I get a server side version of PDFMake ("pdfmake": "^0.1.31") running on Node.js **with the included vfs_fonts.js file?**

Install using npm on command line

```
npm install pdfmake fs --save
```

Boot up a Node.js app index.js with the following:

```
var fonts = {
    Roboto: {
        normal: 'fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf',
        bold: 'fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf',
        italics: 'fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf',
        bolditalics: 'fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf'
    }
};

var PdfPrinter = require('pdfmake/src/printer');
var printer = new PdfPrinter(fonts);

var dd = {
    content: [
        'First paragraph',
        'Another paragraph'
    ]
}
var pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(dd);
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('basics.pdf')).on('finish',function(){
    //success
});
pdfDoc.end();
```

Hit run and bam:

```
/usr/local/bin/node index.js
fs.js:640
  return binding.open(pathModule._makeLong(path), stringToFlags(flags), mode);
                 ^
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:640:18)
```

The problem seems to lie with the location of the fonts/Roboto... files.  Client-side, this is solved by including the vfs_fonts.js file.  Server-side, I'm not sure.  There are NO [fonts folder or .ttf files](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/381) included. The meteor framework [example](https://github.com/daupawar/MeteorAsyncPdfmake) I've found doesn't seem applicable.

Any ideas?  All the official [examples](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/tree/master/examples) reference a src/fonts folder.  Not a good way to go for an npm install server module.

Comment: You don't need to include Roboto font on the server side, it is available by default. If you need custom fonts, then you need to follow the steps mentioned at https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/wiki/Custom-Fonts---client-side

Answer (score 8):

This is what I did to resolve this.

Downloaded "roboto-font": "0.1.0" module and assign path of that fonts in Roboto object and it worked fine.

```
let fonts = {
    Roboto: {
        normal: 'node_modules/roboto-font/fonts/Roboto/roboto-regular-webfont.ttf',
        bold: 'node_modules/roboto-font/fonts/Roboto/roboto-bold-webfont.ttf',
        italics: 'node_modules/roboto-font/fonts/Roboto/roboto-italic-webfont.ttf',
        bolditalics: 'node_modules/roboto-font/fonts/Roboto/roboto-bolditalic-webfont.ttf'
    }
};
let printer = new pdfMake(fonts);
let pdfDoc = printer.createPdfKitDocument(pdfData);
pdfDoc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(reportName));
pdfDoc.end();
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to download first the Roboto font here https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Roboto
and copy them inside you fonts folder.
Update your fonts object like this:

```
var fonts = {
  Roboto: {
    normal: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'your_public_folder', '/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf'),
    bold: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'your_public_folder', '/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf'),
    italics: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'your_public_folder', '/fonts/Roboto-Italic.ttf'),
    bolditalics: path.join(__dirname, '..', 'your_public_folder', '/fonts/Roboto-MediumItalic.ttf')
  }
}
```

In this example, replace the '**your_public_folder**' with folder name where you have all your html, css and js files.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but I was looking for something else:

"Plus, copying fonts into a root "fonts" folder isn't great.

How in the world do I get a server side version of pdfMake ("pdfmake": "^0.1.31") running on NodeJs with the included vfs_fonts.js file?"

Comment: The **vfs_fonts.js** file is only required if you want to use pdfMake on the **client side**. This file is a binary which includes the fonts. You don't need to create this file to use it with nodejs. In nodejs you need to specify a path with your fonts as I answered earlier.